# Java Read XML File in Maven Project - Openshift JBoss

Tags: java, xml, maven, openshift

I would like to read a XML file inside my Maven project in Eclipse Luna. I am using an Openshift Application - JBoss Enterprise. I would like to make it something like this:

`InputStream is = ClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("src/main/resources/XMLFile.xml");`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take `src/main/resources` out of the path and put a forward slash in the beginning. `"/XMLFile.xml"`. Assuming this is a Maven project, the `src/main/resources` will be gone when the project is built/deployed

`class.getResourceAsStream` looks for resources on the classpath. With Maven (which by the looks of your structure, it looks like you're using), will build everything in the `src/main/resources` to the root of the classpath. The `/` signifies searching from the root of the classpath

So basically, it would just look like

```
InputStream is = ClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("/XMLFile.xml");
```

---

As an aside, not sure what the JAX-RS tag and the title reference is for. If you are having problems with anything dealing directly with JAX-RS, please elaborate. Otherwise, please remove the tag and the reference in the title.

Comment: Thank you. Already obtained a value in the InputStream. Edited the question and followed your suggestion.